# iPhone Distribution certificate not reachable in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

Without my iPhone Distribution Certificate set within XCode 4 (on Release and Release-> Any iOS SDK) I get Code Sign Errors when I attempting to upload with Organizer/Application Loader (this is an update to an existing app).

I have the distribution certificate in the keychain but I'm not able to bring it up (or enter it manually, tried name, serial number and user-id) within XCode.

I have attempted deleting and re-installing the certificate, restarting Xcode and the system but I'm not able to correct this.

I have also manually deleted the provisioning links within the .pbxproj file and cleaned but I'm not able to get this to work.

Anyone know how to bring up the distribution certificate within Xcode 4?

Comment: Have you tried clicking refresh in XCode organiser?

Comment: I can't see this option inside the organizer. Where to look?

Comment: I don't have a mac here but i think it's in organizer under library - provisioning profiles (the button itself is on the bottom of the screen). And i'm not sure at which exact version of XCode it was implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the name of your bundle identifier in XCode. Make sure it's same as your certificate identifier name. If it's same as your Distribution certificate identifier name you'll be able to select the certificate easily.

Comment: The certificate name is 'iPhone Distribution: CompanyName'. I've tried having it as the bundle name (also without the 'iphone distribution' part). Also tried the user-id of the key but no luck.

Changing the bundle name gives me new validation error in that it's not the same bundle id as last time (this is an version 1.1 update to existing app).

Comment: Click on your certificate and see the name of bundle identifier. Which is in format of com.compnyname.appname. It should match with the name of your bundle identifier in xcode.

Comment: Are we talking from they keychain editor here? I'm rightclicking both the developer certificates (which work) and the distribution certificate but I can't locate the bundle id in neither (maybe it's the hex values).

Comment: Go to Organiser click on Device. Then click on 'iPhone Distribution: CompanyName'(your distribution certificate). Then in the top section you'll be able to see something called App Identifier. Can u check whether it's same as the name of the Bundle Identifier in XCode.

Comment: Yes, those are equal. If I view the app identifier string under the Provisioning profiles tab it has a license in front (e38djdhssk.company.com) while under the developer tab it's the company.com part showing only.

Comment: Check the XCOde bundle identifier. Go to your Project - Targets - Info and see the name of the Bundle identifier there.

Comment: I have seen the bundle identifier string in Xcode and it's company.com. PS. I never find the distribution certificate name there though ('iPhone Distribution: CompanyName'). Just a provisioning profile with a custom name ('App done').

Comment: I can actually see the distribution certificate under the Developer Profile tab but it does not let me interact. Organization also differ for some reason.

Comment: Rushi, thanks for the help in the chat. I'm new to this and the mistake is on me.  The provisioning profiles for Development and Distribution are two separate ones but since the names are about identical (in my case) I didn't realize this at first. The Distribution profile was never installed to begin with. Thanks.